# Canon 5D Mark IV is taking pictures on it's own

Tags: canon, shutter, preview

The preview on my Canon 5D Mark IV sometimes won't show. When I click on the preview button, the camera takes pictures instead?? Electrical breakdown??

Comment: Did you try to reset the configuration?

Comment: Sounds like the buttons have been re-mapped.